# Deserialising JSON via Jackson with Spring Properties

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Is there an existing utility library that can deserialise json strings via Jackson into objects with some of the String fields containing Spring-loaded properties?

Something like:

```
{
"id": 100,
"name": "Some name",
"imgUrl": "${domain}/user/100.jpg"
}
```

Then on `new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, User.class);` it replaces the fields with the appropriate property values?

Is it done through a custom deserialiser or is there a better approach in doing it?

Cheers!

Comment: You can try autowiring the property bean into your User class using aspectj and read the property from that bean.

Comment: Thanks @ArulKumaran, though does it mean the User class needs to be aware of the property name used? I'd prefer it to be as a simple pojo class as possible, and use Jackson's (potential) extensions to deserialise and process them. :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, I would go with the '{domain}' being a part of the client code(html, jsp, etc..) since its same across all the user objects.